# Google Play music won't play album in order

Tags: google, music

I've made a custom album/playlist and imported it onto my SD card on my phone. However, when I got to play the playlist, not only does it break up the album by artist, it won't even play in order. Every song has a track number, but it seems to be ignoring this. How I can I get it so the album is grouped together regardless of artist AND have it play the playlist in track order?

Comment: Check if the "random" button is on...

Answer (score 1):

Sort by "time". Pick an album and set it. That will change the settings when playing the songs in the database. It will re-order the songs to the way they were loaded onto the memory card. They were originally loaded with a time stamp in sequential order, with one being slightly older than the other. It appears to be ignoring the proper order. That is how I got it to work without downloading another player. Nothing worse than trying to play "The Wall" out of order!

Answer (score 0):

To play all songs by an artist when in Artist view, click the picture or album art to the left of their name. This will start playing a random song and then you can click the Mini Player at the bottom and you should then see the option to shuffle if it's not already enabled.